# Move files to a folder using event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, event-receivers

Hi I have an Infopath form Library and i want to add the forms that are being submitted to a folder in the same library according to the information

I need to do this using an event receiver.
Can someone please help with some basic code segement

Answer (score 1):

So I guess this is what you're looking for:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    var myListItem = properties.ListItem;
    var myList = properties.List;

    if (myListItem != null)
    {
        string condition = myListItem["SomeCondition"].ToString();
        if (condition == "x")
        {
            myListItem.File.MoveTo("/ConditionXPath/" + myListItem.File.Name);                       
        }
        else if (condition == "y")
        {
            myListItem.File.MoveTo("/ConditionYPath/" + myListItem.File.Name);       
        }
        else
        {
            //..
        }                                
    }           
}
```